# How to load image from directory, then show onclick

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I am trying to have a function which has functions that do the following.
One function to store the files i get with input into the parent functions loadedimages array(loadimages).
One function to show those files in the correct component(showLoadedImages).
And one function to make the correct img file appear on the correct component.
The last function is what i want it to be like(it does not work).
The other two seem ok.
The problem i have is how to make the last function work while using the loadedimages array. You can change what i store in the array , i wouldnt mind.

Here is the JS code:

```
function imgviewer() {
    "use strict";
    var loadedimages = [];
    var lidivs = [];

    function loadimages() {
        var files = document.getElementById("images").files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
                alert('THERE IS NO IMAGE IN THIS DIRECTORY.');
                break;
            }
            loadedimages.push(file);
        }
    }

    function showLoadedImages(elem) {
        loadimages();
        var ld = loadedimages;

        //var files = getLoadedImages(); //filelist obj
        for (var i = 0; i < ld.length; i++) {
            var file = ld[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function(file) {
                return function(e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var span = document.createElement(
                        'span');
                    span.innerHTML = [
                        '<img class="tile" src="',
                        e.target.result,
                        '" title="', encodeURI(
                            file.name), '">'
                    ].join('');
                    document.getElementById(elem).insertBefore(
                        span, null);
                    lidivs.push(span);
                };
            })(file);
            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    function showImage(index, elem) {
        var chosenFile = loadedimages[index];
        document.getElementById(elem).src = chosenFile;
    }
document.getElementById('images').addEventListener('change', function(){
    showLoadedImages("main");
    }, false);
}
```

And some HTML

```
<form name="uploadForm">
<input id="images" type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory directory      name="myFiles"
multiple/>
<span id="list"></span>
</form>
<div id="sidebar1"><img id="willchange" src="images/railaythailand.jpg"   width="1200" height="832" alt=""/></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

When i call showLoadedImages("main") the images are shown in main div. I want to be able to click those images so that they appear on "willchange" .

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some HTML to go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you asked for.  There are a number of other issues with your code that you might want to address, starting with the images are not thumbnails at all (and shrunken images take just as long to load as the original),  but perhaps I'm missing something.

```js
"use strict";
var loadedimages = [];
var lidivs = [];

function loadimages() {
 var files = document.getElementById("images").files;
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];
  if (!file.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
   continue;
  }
  loadedimages.push(file);
 }
    loadedimages.length || alert('THERE IS NO IMAGE IN THIS DIRECTORY.');
}

function showLoadedImages(elem) {
 loadimages();
 var ld = loadedimages;

 //var files = getLoadedImages(); //filelist obj
 for (var i = 0; i < ld.length; i++) {
  var file = ld[i];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(file) {
   return function(e) {
    // Render thumbnail.
    var span = document.createElement(
     'span');
    span.innerHTML = [
     '<img data-index="',
     lidivs.length,
     '" class="tile" src="',
     e.target.result,
     '" title="', encodeURI(
      file.name), '">'
    ].join('');
    span.addEventListener("click", foo );
    document.getElementById(elem).insertBefore(
     span, null);
    lidivs.push(span);
   };
  })(file);
  // Read in the image file as a data URL.
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
}

function showImage(index, elem) {
 document.getElementById(elem).src = lidivs[index].children[0].src;
}

function foo(event) {
  showImage(event.target.dataset.index, "willchange");
}

function show() {
    showLoadedImages("list");
}

function init() {
 document.getElementById("images").addEventListener("change", show, false);
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
```

```html
<body>
<form name="uploadForm">
<input id="images" type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory directory      name="myFiles"
multiple/>
<span id="list"></span>
</form>
<div id="sidebar1"><img id="willchange" src="images/railaythailand.jpg"   width="1200" height="832" alt=""/></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this answered my question, thank you.
Do you mind telling me the other issues you mentioned?
(the shrunked images are ok).
Also how would you go making this into an api?

Comment: @GioKar You're doing things like storing the same data 3 times.  You have the files in loadedimages, in lidivs and in the page itself.  There's other little things, but you should ask this as a question on the code review site.